# Regex: Match image URL in GitHub markdown?

Tags: javascript, regex, github, markdown

This is probably a very simple question, but I am awful at regex.

I want to match the image in GitHub markdown such as this:

```
![Icon](icon.png?raw=true)
![Icon](icon.jpg?raw=true)
![Icon](thumb.jpg?raw=true)
![Icon](icon512.png?raw=true)
![Icon](android-chrome-512x512.png?raw=true)
```

I'm trying to match the following:

```
icon.png?raw=true
icon.jpg?raw=true
thumb.jpg?raw=true
icon512.png?raw=true
android-chrome-512x512.png?raw=true
```

I'm trying to only match .jpg and .png files, if possible (including ?raw=true).

I have no clue if this is possible, but since I am using Javascript's [match](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp) function, it would be very helpful if there was only a single match, to avoid indexing the matches as I am below:

**EDIT:** Here's some context, this is what I am trying:

```js
var paths = [
  "![Icon](icon.png?raw=true)",
  "![Icon](icon.jpg?raw=true)",
  "![Icon](thumb.jpg?raw=true)",
  "![Icon](icon512.png?raw=true)",
  "![Icon](android-chrome-512x512.png?raw=true)"
]

for (var i = 0; i < paths.length; i++) {
  console.log(paths[i].match(/(?<=\!\[Icon]\()(.*)(?=\))/g)[0]);
}
```

Obviously, this regex is a huge mess. I just made to demonstrate what I am trying to do.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have made any attempt to write anything yourself yet? Post the code you've tried

Comment: @CertainPerformance updated post with my awful regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could first match the `![Icon](`, then capture in group 1 what is between the parenthesis and at the end match a closing parenthesis again.

[`!\[Icon\]\((.+?\.(?:png|jpg)[^)]*)\)`](https://regex101.com/r/F65DM2/1)

- `!\[Icon\]` Match ![Icon]
- `\(` Match opening parenthesis
- `(` Capturing group which will contain the value you want to match

  - `.+?` Match any character one or more times non greedy
  - `\.` Match a dot
  - `(?:png|jpg)` Non capturing group which will match png or jpg
  - `[^)]*` Negated character class that will match zero or more times not a closing parenthesis
- `)` Close capturing group
- `\)` Match closing parenthesis

```js
var paths = [
  "![Icon](icon.png?raw=true)",
  "![Icon](icon.jpg?raw=true)",
  "![Icon](thumb.jpg?raw=true)",
  "![Icon](icon512.png?raw=true)",
  "![Icon](android-chrome-512x512.png?raw=true)"
];

for (var i = 0; i < paths.length; i++) {
  console.log(paths[i].match(/!\[Icon\]\((.+?\.(?:png|jpg)[^)]*)\)/)[1]);
}
```

Update:

To only match a png and a jpg using a positive lookbehind you might use:

[`(?<=!\[Icon]\().*?\.(?:png|jpg)(?=[^)]*\))`](https://regex101.com/r/0H12Bd/1)

```js
var paths = [
  "![Icon](icon.png?raw=true)",
  "![Icon](icon.jpg?raw=true)",
  "![Icon](thumb.jpg?raw=true)",
  "![Icon](icon512.png?raw=true)",
  "![Icon](android-chrome-512x512.png?raw=true)"
];

for (var i = 0; i < paths.length; i++) {
  console.log(paths[i].match(/(?<=!\[Icon]\().*?\.(?:png|jpg)(?=[^)]*\))/g)[0]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this! I upvote all answers, I don't know who downvoted. This seems to work very well, but I just wanted to ask if it would be possible to avoid a group match, only matching the URL? When I test the expression with Javascript, the match function returns both the match group as well as the full match. It works if I index the returned value with [0], but I am just hoping there might be a way to get around this

Comment: You can use the version with the positive lookbehind [`(?<=!\[Icon]\().*?(?=\))`](https://regex101.com/r/2iGaVv/1). In this version `(.*)` is changed to `.*?` because you don't need the capturing group for the match and now it is non greedy to match the first closing parenthesis. Note that the positive lookbehind is not supported in all browsers.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I was looking for! Please add this as an answer so I can accept it. Also, I don't know if this is possible, but would it be possible to make it only match .jpg and .png?

Comment: @MysteryPancake That is possible. I have added an update to my answer.

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect. Sorry for another tiny request, this is not important so you don't have to bother with this, but I was wondering if it would also be possible to include the `?raw=true`? I really meant the image path if it is a .png or .jpg, but including everything until the next bracket.

Comment: Sure, you could use a negated character class `[^)]*` after matching jpg or png to match not a closing parenthesis [`(?<=!\[Icon]\().*?\.(?:png|jpg)[^)]*(?=\))`](https://regex101.com/r/0H12Bd/2)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not able to understand what you really want to do but the regex for what you expect is something like this:

```
\!\[Icon\]\(((?:.*)\.(?:png|jpg).*)\)
```

This will get images with extensions and ?raw=true or something appended to it only:

```
icon.png?raw=true icon.jpg?raw=true thumb.jpg?raw=true icon512.png?raw=true android-chrome-512x512.png?raw=true
```

Comment: Thank you! I am just wondering if it would be possible to match the entire file name and nothing else (including ?raw=true)

Comment: Updated the answer please check

Comment: Thank you for all of this work! I apologise greatly for this, but I just have one more request: would it be possible to match only one thing? When I test the expression with Javascript, the match function returns both the match group as well as the full match. It works if I index the returned value with [0], but I am just hoping there might be a way to get around this

Comment: Did you downvoted all other answers here? Seems like it, your answer is the only one that didn't got downvoted and you have three votes cast today. Plus, your answer is very similair to @Thefourthbird answer.

Comment: @MichałTurczyn Upvoted all the answers Hope you know that they can't be changed after 1 hour of voting once.

Answer (score 0):

This will grab the string like 'icon.png?raw=true' and place it in the first capture group

```
!\[Icon\]\((.+)\)
```

If you just want the image URL you can use this:

```
!\[Icon\]\((.+\.\w+).*\)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern: `\((?P<filename>.+?(\.png|\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.bmp))`.

Capturing group named `filename` will contain file name.

Explanation:

first, match `(` with pattern `\(`. Then, start named capturing group: any character one or more times, non-greedy, until some image extension `.+?(\.png|\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.bmp)`. Non-greediness is important, because if the file would be followed by another file name with on of our extensions, it would match until the second file.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/CajdQG/4)

**EDIT**:

OP: *I am just wondering if it would be possible to match the entire file name and nothing else?*

Answer: yes, just use this pattern: `(?<=\().+(\.png|\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.bmp)` with positive lookbehind.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/CajdQG/6)

Comment: Thank you! I am just wondering if it would be possible to match the entire file name and nothing else